# Extract just the required functions from  a C code project?

Tags: c, linux, refactoring

How can I extract just the required functions from a pile of C source files? Is there a tool which can be used on GNU/Linux?

Preferably FOSS, but the GNU/Linux is a hard requirement.

Basically I got about 10 `.h` files; I'd like to grab part of the code and get the required variables from the header files. Then I can make a single small `.h` file corresponding to the code I'm using in another project.

My terms might not be 100% correct.

Comment: What does "required functions" mean to you??? Your question is probably untractable or undecidable [think of function pointers, `dlsym`]....

Comment: looks like I'll need to get variables from header files.  I'm a Linux SysAdmin, while my scripting is great... My c knowledge is horrifically lacking.

Comment: In the past I've used LLVM link time optimization which internalized all identifiers other than main. Unreferenced functions were removed. I had to take pains to keep things like interrupt handlers from getting removed. It's not a source level solution, though.

Comment: Or you could start by compiling main() and add functions until you don't get any more linker errors. :-)

Comment: @ Richard Pennington: That's exactly what I have now, but is that really my only option?  I was really hoping some tools exist, which would at least help this process.

Comment: Usually you don't simplify header files — you just use the ones provided with the version of the library you're using. Why do you want to separate them?

Comment: @TechZilla: it is an undecidable problem (not a matter of C specifically), if your code is general enough.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: It is not an undecidable problem, otherwise the whole link time concept would be impossible. You could do this with static analyses. Instead of throwing an error at stdout, you search the specified files for the missing variable or function.

Comment: @Kevin Reid: who ever said this was a library?  If it was a library, I would include it and call it a day.  This is an entire project, of which one specific thing needs to be used somewhere else.  I wish it was a library, then I wouldn't have this type of problem.

Comment: If you are going to do this just once, what's the problem with just simply doing it?  If you grab code and fail to grab a declaration on which it depends, the compiler will let you know the name of the thing you are missing so the process is iterative but easy.   Or are you going to do this repeatedly?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: I partly addressed this on the 5th comment down.  As far as repeatedly, I would assume I'll be doing this anytime I use code from a non-library project.

Comment: It is certainly undecidable once you use `dlsym` on constructed (i.e. arbitrary) names to get functions.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I don't know enough about your example, so I cannot argue against it. I would however assume, while the problem may be undecidable in that type of case, it is decidable in most cases.  Or at the very least, could help break down a large list.

Comment: Actually, even with strictly standard C, actual reachability of a given function is undecidable. Think of `if (expression_known_to_be_false_difficult_to_be_proved_false()) foo(x);` then you might not want to "link in" `foo` even if it is syntactically called, because you might know that the test is never true. Actually, standard `assert` is nearly like that. or just `int *p; /*some code*/ *p = 1; if (!p) foo();` the compiler is permitted to optimize and remove that call to `foo` because, since `p` has been dereferenced, it cannot be null.

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch: This needs to be done on the source level, and with the assumption that any code referenced should be included.   The amount of work to clean up any mishaps, would be far less than doing everything manually. The objective is not, find a tool that can be used as a programmer, it is about possibly reducing the manual refactoring work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool that you may or may not be aware of is [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/).  It can be used to help you.

For a given set of files (more on what that means shortly), it gives you these options:

```
Find this C symbol:
Find this global definition:
Find functions called by this function:
Find functions calling this function:
Find this text string:
Change this text string:
Find this egrep pattern:
Find this file:
Find files #including this file:
```

Thus, if you know you want to use a function `humungous_frogmondifier()`, you can find where it is declared or defined by typing its name (or pasting its name) after 'Find this global definition'.  If you then want to know what functions it calls, you use the next line.  Once you've hit return after specifying the name, you will be given a list of the relevant lines in the source files above this menu on the screen.  You can page through the list (if there are more entries than will fit on the screen), and at any time select one of the shown entries by number or letter, in which case `cscope` launches your editor on the file.

How about that list of files?  If you run `cscope` in a directory without any setup, it will scan the source files in the directory and build its cross-reference.  However, if you prefer, you can set up a list of files names in `cscope.files` and it will analyze those files instead.  You can also include `-I /path/to/directory` on the cscope command line and it will find referenced headers in those directories too.

I'm using cscope 15.7a on some sizeable projects - depending on which version of the project, between about 21,000 and 25,000 files (and some smaller ones with only 10-15 thousand files).  It takes about half an hour to set up this project (so I carefully rebuild the indexes once per night, and use the files for the day, accepting that they are a little less accurate at the end of the day).  It allows me to track down unused stuff, and find out where stuff is used, and so on.

If you're used to an IDE, it will be primitive.  If you're used to curses-mode programs (`vim`, etc), then it is tolerably friendly.

Comment: I'll be using scope, and ctags with Komodo editor. Komodo has Vi Emulation and ctags plugin. Thanks for the input, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You suggest (in comments to the main question) that you will be doing this more than once, possibly on different (non-library) code bases.    I'm not sure I see the big value in this; I've been coding C on an off for 30+ years and don't feel the need to do this very often.

But given the assumption you will, what you really want is a tool that can, for a given identifier in a system of C files and headers, find the definition of that identifier in those files, and compute the transitive closure of all the dependencies which it has.  This defines a partial order over the definitions based on the depends-on relationship.  Finally you want to emit the code for those definitions to an output file, in a linear order that honors the partial order determined.  (You can simplify this a bit by insisting that the identifier you want is in a particular C compilation unit, but the rest of it stays the same).

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) can be used to do this.   DMS is a general purpose program transformation system, capable of parsing source files into ASTs, perform full name resolution (e.g., building symbol tables), [do flow analysis but this isn't needed for your task].  Given those ASTs and the symbol tables, it can be configured to compute this transitive dependency using the symbol table information which record where symbols are defined in the ASTs.  Finally, it can be configured to assemble the ASTs of interest into a linear order honoring the partial order.

We have done all this with DMS in the past, where the problem was to generate SOA-like interfaces based on other criteria; after generating the SOA code, the tool picked out all the dependencies for the SOA code and did exactly what was required.  The dependency extraction machinery is part of the C front end.

A complication for the C world is that the preprocessor may get in the way; for the particular task we accomplished, the extraction was done over a specific configuration of the application and so the preprocessor directives were all expanded away.    If you want this done and retain the C preprocessor directives, you'll need something beyond what DMS can do today.  (We do have experimental work that captures macros and preprocessor conditionals in the AST but that's not ready for release to production).

You'd think this problem would be harder with C++ but it is not, because the prepreprocessor is used far more lightly in C++ programs.  While we have not done extraction for C++, it would follow exactly the same approach as for C.

So that's the good part with respect to your question.

The not so good  part from your point of view, perhaps, is that DMS isn't FOSS; it is a commercial tool designed to be used by my company and our customers to build custom analysis and transformation tools for all those tasks you can't get off the shelf, that make economic sense.    Nor does DMS run natively on Linux, rather it is a Windows based tool.  It can reach across the network using NFS to access files on other systems including Linux.  DMS does run under Wine on Linux.